# Changing iOS BarChart xAxis label position

Tags: ios-charts

I am using excellent iOS Chart library for creating graphs. (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/)

Here is what I am be able to do:

[image: capture d ecran 2017-06-15 a 15 31 41]

I would to have labels like this:

[image: capture d ecran 2017-06-15 a 15 31 41 copie]

Do you know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shift the index by 0.5 and set xAxis.axisMinimum to 0.0:

```
    var entries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []


    for index in 0..<datapoints.count {
        let value1 = Double(datapoints[index])
        let value2 = Double(datapoints[index])

        entries.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(index)+0.5, yValues: [value1, value2]))

    }

    let xvalues = ["1", "2"]
    combinedChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: xvalues)

    combinedChart.xAxis.labelPosition = Charts.XAxis.LabelPosition.bothSided

    let set = BarChartDataSet(values: entries, label: " - Description.")

    combinedChart.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0

    set.axisDependency = Charts.YAxis.AxisDependency.left
    data.addDataSet(set)
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to complete this job.

- First method

  ```
  chartView.setExtraOffsets(left: 20, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0)
  ```
- Second method

  ```
  chartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use offset

```
combinedChart.xAxis.xOffset = -0.5
```

I am not sure if the value is correct for your case. Try it out a little bit.